# Web api настройка fluent api

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Добрый день!
У меня случилась проблема!
Не могу понять, почему не получаю модель Result.

Вот модели данных.

```
public class Claims
{
    public int id_claim { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<ClaimResultsHistories> ClaimResultsHistory { get; set; }
}
public class ClaimResultsHistories
{
    public int? id_result_history { get; set; }
    public int? id_claim { get; set; }
    public int? id_result { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public DateTime? date_add { get; set; }
    public Claims Claims { get; set; }
    public Results Results { get; set; }
}
public class Results
{
    public int? id_result { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
    public int? id_result_type { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClaimResultsHistories> ClaimResultsHistories { get; set; }
}
```

это контекст данных

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClaimResultsHistories>().HasKey(k=>k.id_result_history).Property(p=>p.id_result_history).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Results>().HasKey(k => k.id_result).Property(p => p.id_result).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Claims>()
            .HasKey(k => k.id_claim)
            .HasMany(k => k.ClaimResultsHistory)
            .WithRequired(k => k.Claims)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.id_claim)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Results>()
            .HasKey(k => k.id_result)
            .HasMany(k=>k.ClaimResultsHistories)
            .WithRequired(k=>k.Results)                
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.id_result)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

и собственно контроллер

```
public class ClaimsController : ApiController 
{

    private ClaimContext db = new ClaimContext();

    public IQueryable<DTO> GetClaims()
    {
        var result = from b in db.Claims select new DTO
        {
            id_claim = b.id_claim,
            description = b.description,
            ClaimResultsHistory = b.ClaimResultsHistory,
        };
        return result;
    }
}
public class DTO
{
    public int id_claim { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClaimResultsHistories> ClaimResultsHistory { get; set; }
}
```

И получаю вот такой ответ

```
"id_claim": 1,
"description": "TEST",
"ClaimResultsHistory": [
  {
    "id_result_history": 1,
    "id_claim": 1,
    "id_result": 2,
    "note": "NOTE TEST",
    "date_add": "2016-04-21T19:57:50.477",
    "Claims": null,
    "Results": null
  },
  {
    "id_result_history": 2,
    "id_claim": 1,
    "id_result": 4,
    "note": "NOTE 2 TEST",
    "date_add": "2016-04-21T19:57:58.38",
    "Claims": null,
    "Results": null
  }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework использует [Lazy Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) для подгрузки связанных объектов и коллекций. Но для того чтобы это работало как надо свойства объектов модели должны быть `virtual`:

```
public class Claims
{
    public int id_claim { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<ClaimResultsHistories> ClaimResultsHistory { get; set; }
}
public class ClaimResultsHistories
{
    public int? id_result_history { get; set; }
    public int? id_claim { get; set; }
    public int? id_result { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public DateTime? date_add { get; set; }
    public virtual Claims Claims { get; set; }
    public virtual Results Results { get; set; }
}
public class Results
{
    public int? id_result { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
    public int? id_result_type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClaimResultsHistories> ClaimResultsHistories { get; set; }
}
```